# is not it the same personal passive?

Tags: grammar

I see it looks like a personal passive

Subjunctive with verbs ( suggest , recommend, advise etc...)

Here is example : The mother recommended that her son….**be**  by his friends all day.

Suppose we use :  It is recommended that or it is suggested that, how does it look ?

Example:  It is recommended that her son be accompanied by his
friends all day.

Is it possible to suggest an example in the way I wrote above ?

Does it not look like an example of impersonal passive ?

---

Comment: I have read this example in  Oxford Practice Grammar Advanced - Page 167 :  We have already recommended that young children not be left alone in parked cars.

Comment: It's not relevant, but you say "accompany by" not "accompany with"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "It is recommended that ..." is an example of an impersonal passive.

And Yes, the verb "recommend" can prompt the subjunctive in the following clause.  "... that he be ...".  So this part of the example sentence has no error.

The impersonal style is highly formal, suitable for legalese rather than normal prose.

Comment: Thank you very much.  You are great.  Believe me I didn't read it anywhere , but I myself thought of